# How to set a proc to run only in order to make a condition true in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, proc

I have a hash of `:symbols => values`, the values of which will be either a fixnum or a boolean. I have to run a loop that'll call each (&:symbol) to be called on the main argument.

The default hash I'm working with is:

```
default_options = {
        :times => 1,
        :upcase => false,
        :reverse => false,
    }
```

And the loop I'm using to call them, assuming I've passed an options hash through the method to change one of the defaults and merged them.

```
hash.each do |key,val|
        unless hash[key] == default_options[key]
            result = key.to_proc.call(string)
        end
    end
```

So basically, if I pass an options hash that changed the defaults, it's supposed to run each proc. If I pass `:times => 5`, it should print the string 5 times, it should print it upcased if I put `:upcase => true`, etc in the options hash. So how do you write the proc in symbol form to receive arguments, or make a boolean prove true?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand either part of your last sentence. Also, in your second code block, are `string` and `val` supposed to be the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what code you'd generate here since `times` and `upcase` can't chain properly.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to do too many things in the block. I'd break the goal down a little and do each step long hand, then re-factor it if you see the opportunity. But don't try to pre-optimise the solution. e.g. 1. merge the defaults, 2. run the merged options over the string.

Answer (score 0):

This will kind of do what I think you want, but you shouldn't go messing with String like I did (just to add the times method).

```
String.instance_exec { alias_method :times, :* }

def do_it(string, **options)
  default_options = {
    times: 3,
    upcase: false,
    reverse: false,
  }

  default_options.merge(options).each do |key, value|
    if value
      string = value == true ? string.public_send(key) : string.public_send(key, value)
    end
  end

  string
end
```

Note, I didn't use to_proc here because it's easier to just call the method.